# API calls are not working in IE when I run a Angular5 application in IE browser

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, observable, angular5

When I am running my local angular application in Chrome its working fine. But in IE-11 drop-down values are not getting populated. Those drop-down values I getting from API call. In IE Consol, I am getting following errors:

ERROR ReferenceError: 'Headers' is undefined
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
ERROR ReferenceError: 'Headers' is undefined
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

[image: IE console error]

Please someone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be useful to know what code fails.

Comment: toskv, I made a mistake, I have resolved the issue its working fine now. Appreciate your reply.

Comment: @LavanyaKomarasamy: would be helpful for other users if you could post what was the issue exactly was and the fix too.

Comment: Solution: the problem was I declared the Header for my rest API call but I didn't use it. So I have removed that unwanted thing. we can find the line where we did mistake by clicking on errors listed in the IE console itself.